# How to easily create a fixed header in list view asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net, listview

I am trying to keep my header fixed while scrolling but I can't figure it out.

Here is my ListView Code:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="FormSectionSubSectionItemRelID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Here is my sites.css table css code:

```
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
margin-top: 0.75em;
border: 0 none;
}

th {
font-size: 1.2em;
text-align: left;
border: none 0px;
padding-left: 0;
}

th a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;

}

th a:link, th a:visited, th a:active, th a:hover {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0;
}

th a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

th.asc a, th.desc a {
    margin-right: .75em;
}

th.asc a:after, th.desc a:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0em;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}

th.asc a:after {
    content: '▲';
}

th.desc a:after {
    content: '▼';
}

td {
padding: 0.25em 2em 0.25em 0em;
border: 0 none;
}

tr.pager td {
padding: 0 0.25em 0 0;
}
```

If there is a property a property I could change or change my css code then that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you could take your code from server side as well and create a demo of your code it would be very helpful in solving this problem for you.

Just looking through your code however, seeing as how you are asking about trying to get something to be fixed at the top of your page and i see in your css code an absolute positioned element at the top of the page i am assuming you wish for THIS element to be fixed while scrolling?

If this is the case then you need to change this code from absolute to fixed.

```
th.asc a:after, th.desc a:after {
  display: block;
  position: fixed; //fixed will not scroll with the page, where absolute will.
  right: 0em;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

Comment: Even after changing it to fixed the header still scrolls up as I scroll. I would like for the header to stay with the page as I scroll.

Comment: Can you create a www.jsfiddle.net example with code that most closely reflects what your website generates? If you can do that i can try to help you, otherwise im guessing.